# Php Mailer erro no hostgator

Tags: php, phpmailer

Esse erro que esta dando espero que alguem me ajude por favor.Obrigado

> (Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate
>   CN=`'*.hostgator.com.br'` did not match expected
>   CN=`'mail.systembit.com.br'` in
>   /home/syste058/public_html/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php on line 344 Erro
>   ao enviar e-mail: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

CÓDIGO PHP

```
<?php
// Caminho da biblioteca PHPMailer
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$Vai        = "name: $name\n\n\email: $email\n\n\assunto: $assunto\n\ntel: $tel\n\n\mensagem: $mensagem\n";

$servidor     = (isset($_POST['servidor-smtp'])) ? $_POST['servidor-smtp'] : 'mail.systembit.com.br';

$porta        = (isset($_POST['porta'])) ? $_POST['porta'] : '25';

$encriptacao  = (isset($_POST['encriptacao'])) ? $_POST['encriptacao'] : 'true';

$usuario      = (isset($_POST['usuario'])) ? $_POST['usuario'] :'contato@systembit.com.br';

$senha        = (isset($_POST['senha'])) ? $_POST['senha'] : '****';

$name    = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] :'';

$email      = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

$tel      = (isset($_POST['tel'])) ? $_POST['tel'] : '';

$assunto      = (isset($_POST['assunto'])) ? $_POST['assunto'] : 'Mensagem do site System Bit';

$cabecalho    = "Email enviado por : ".$name." na data ".date('d-m-y H:i')."<br />\n";

$destinatario = (isset($_POST['destinatario'])) ? $_POST['destinatario']: 'contato@systembit.com.br';

$mensagem     = (isset($_POST['mensagem'])) ? $_POST['mensagem'] : '';


// Instância do objeto PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;

// Configura o charset do e-mail
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

// Configura para envio de e-mails usando SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

// Servidor SMTP
$mail->Host = $servidor;

// Usar autenticação SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

// Usuário da conta
$mail->Username = $usuario;

// Senha da conta
$mail->Password = $senha;

// Tipo de encriptação que será usado na conexão SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = $encriptacao;

// Porta do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = $porta;

// Informa se vamos enviar mensagens usando HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

// Email do Remetente
$mail->From = $email;

// Nome do Remetente
$mail->FromName = $name;

// Endereço do e-mail do destinatário
$mail->addAddress($destinatario);

// Assunto do e-mail
$mail->Subject = $assunto;

// Mensagem que vai no corpo do e-mail
$mail->Body = $cabecalho.$email.$tel.$mensagem;

// Envia o e-mail e captura o sucesso ou erro
if($mail->Send()):
    echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
else:
    echo "Erro ao enviar e-mail: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";

endif;
```

Comment: tenta ver a versão do php usada no site, e também se a hostgator não tem algum bloqueio referente aos envios e recebimentos de formulários por email como a locaweb, que possui um sistema em que você só pode enviar e receber se tiver emails próprios do seu domínio ou da hostgator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O PHP valida certificados SSL. Aparentemente você não tem um certificado válido para `mail.systembit.com.br` no seu sistema.

Enquanto a solução correta é instalar um certificado válido, um *work-around* mais imediato é desativar a validação:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

---

#### Fontes:

1. [SOen - PHPMailer generates PHP Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate did not match expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30371910/664577)
2. [PHPMailer - SSL certificate is not verified](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/196)

Comment: Coloco la no class.smtp.php na linha 344?  $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

Comment: Você pode aplicar essas configurações em qualquer linha após construir a instância de `PHPMailer` e antes de chamar `$mail->Send();`

Comment: Agora foi ,valew maninho muito obrigado tenha um bom dia

Comment: Oi Jeferson, fico feliz por ter ajudado. Se essa resposta resolveu seu problema não se esqueça de aceitá-la. Abraços.

Answer (score -4):

Galera após muito testes descobri o que é esse problema no hostgator.
É a merda das permissões nas pastas. Coloca em 755 e seja feliz.
FDPS deixam tudo em 750